# What should I enter as server URL?

Tags: 7

I have a Drupal site on Amazon server. On the amazon server, I have created an Elasticsearch server. I want to connect my Drupal instance with that server so I can use the search server for performing the search operation on the site.

I added and configured the [Elasticsearch connector](https://www.drupal.org/project/elasticsearch_connector) module which, in order to connect to the search server, needs I create a cluster which would help in connecting both the instances.

While adding a cluster to the Drupal instance, it asks me about the server URL. I am not sure on what I should write as server URL. What should I add in that form field?

[image]

Comment: Had you been able to connect Drupal with AWS ElasticSearch cluster ?

Answer (score 2):

Just enter the Endpoint of your AWS Elastic-search Cluster.

Use port : "80".

the Complete url will be something like:

XXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXX.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com:80

First check are you able to access the Elastic-search , Try to telnet on the server:

telnet XXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXX.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com 80

If it's not accessible make it available for your IP by changing the access policy .

Comment: I have tried the above but it never finds any alive nodes

Comment: @DanielHarper  are you able to access the Elastic-search instance?

Comment: Yes I can, it is limited to IP address but I can access it from my location and I'm working on a local Drupal installation. I do have elastic on a separate EC2 instance and I can connect to that using IP and port number 9200. I know the aws elastic search service runs on port 80 so I have tried lots of different combinations.